# What does "dam broke" mean?

Tags: bill-and-ted

In *Bill & Ted Face the Music (2020)*, Bill & Ted time traveled to 2025, San Dimas:

> Bill: Dude, look at where we live!
>
> Ted: One song did all this?
>
> Bill: Ted, what if it wasn't just one song? What if after we wrote it
> and saved the universe, a **dam broke** and the songs just kept comin' and
> comin'?

What does "dam broke" mean?

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour], but don't feel pressured to accept the first answer that comes in.

Comment: Needs migration to english language stack exchange

Comment: @user13267: No, we allow for explanation of terms in SF&F as per https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/is-it-reasonable-to-ask-about-the-meaning-of-phrases-in-a-science-fiction-work. FWIW, the Literature SE also allows it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a [dam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dam) breaks, all of the water it's holding back rushes through, generally breaking the dam further and releasing more water, often [causing a flood](https://www.costaricantimes.com/dam-metaphors/52289) to happen. This is a metaphor that if they write one successful song, then more will follow just like if there's a small break in the dam and some water comes out, soon the entire dam may break, releasing all of the pent-up water.